# Why are there no local functions in C?

Tags: c

Is there a technical reason why C does not have local functions? Is it perhaps an implementation issue?

Comment: I don't think you're going to get a better answer than "because the creators of C didn't think of it/want it"...

Comment: C was designed with minimalism as a goal. Relatively few keywords, features, etc. makes it fairly easy to write compilers for. There's no technical reason that local (nested) functions couldn't be implemented.. and in fact nested functions are available as a GNU C extension (not part of ANSI C).. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html

Comment: Local functions are an ugly (require executable stack, and thus open security vulns) way of doing what you can already do by using a pair `(func_ptr, context_ptr)` instead of a bare function pointer.

Comment: @R..: do you mean anonymous functions? He means nested functions, AFAICT.

Comment: Nested functions serve only one real point: allowing one to bundle data with a function pointer for use with interfaces that require a callback but don't allow a separate data context pointer. And unfortunately they're still not really full closures because they go out of scope... I suppose one other use is laziness (accessing the caller's local vars without putting them in a struct and passing the pointer)......